# 2 master pages one user control, how do I find what master page is being used?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

So I have 2 master pages and one user control which is used on almost every page. Page may have one of 2 master pages and both master pages have one property common. It is a list variable that I need access. How do I know which master page is being used and then access it?

I am trying

```
MasterPage mp = (MasterPage)this.Page.Master;
```

but when I debug, I don't see the list property. mp.List doesn't work. Any idea on how to get this property?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do the master pages implement an interface that you can cast to in order to get the property?

Comment: no the master pages don't implement any interfaces

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a simple interface to make this easy.

```
public interface IHasProperty 
{
   List<string> MyVariable {get;set;}
}

public partial class MasterPage1 : (other stuff), IHasProperty
{
   List<string> MyVariable {get;set;}
}

public partial class MasterPage2 : (other stuff), IHasProperty
{
   List<string> MyVariable {get;set;}
}
```

then from the user control, you can access this by using something like this.

```
var myPropPage = Page.Master as IHasProperty;
if (myPropPage == null)
{
   //this property isnt on the page.
   return;
}

myPropPage.MyVariable.Add("new Value");// or whatever you needed to do with it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a strongly typed reference to the master page on your aspx as so:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.Master" %>
```

Then in the code behind you can do this.Master without having to cast and the list should be accessible.

Comment: I have 2 master pages which depend on the page being loaded. User control is just a common thing among all the pages.

Comment: Master pages shouldn't depend on it's child pages. Should be the other way around

Comment: I was trying to edit after I saw your comment and what I really meant was the page has the user control and depending on the page the Master page is selected. I think I may have solved the problem. Once I get it working without any bugs I will post the solution

Comment: So your trying to access the master page from the child page or the user control inside the child page?